# How to fix the computer?? Typed sudo shred -rfz ~/* (or something like that)

Tags: tags, shred

One *&^%@&*& advised me to press alt+f2 and then type the above. And i did it... on my Dad's computer. He's furious now. How to fix this?

Comment: Seriously? You think we can help if you ask something like this? What operating system are you on? What do you mean "something like that"? If you are on a *nix system (sounds like Linux running Gnome, is that correct?) and you ran `sudo shred -rfz ~/*` you're basically screwed. Not really anything you can do. You just destroyed your dad's data. Wow, he lets you play on his computer with _his_ username? I bet he won't anymore.

Comment: dude... you shan't be just hammerin' code into your computer if you don't even know what it does... at least verify it with someone competent beforehand.

Comment: shred is created to delete data permanently, without even leaving "unlinked" blocks on disk with original data. So you've really lost all the current user home content. Now, press alt+f2 and write `sudo transferMoney from=me to=aCharity amount=all`… it'd be a self-explanatory command, so you can decide to run it or not.

Answer (score 2):

you basically deleted his user... and all files in it. The machine is not lost, but I am pretty sure the user data is gone for ever.

The key options here was the use of the home directory of the user ~/* and the **very wicked z** option of shred

[shred](/questions/tagged/shred)http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man1/shred.1.html

Comment: The user won't be deleted, just the user's data. The user is still in the system, he'll just have an empty `$HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

Let this be a lesson in doing your own research before taking any advice. A simple `man` page lookup from the command line would have warned you off.

Linux has a manual system invoked by typing `man` at the command prompt.

Lets trace out what you were instructed to do.

`man sudo`

> **sudo** allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user

So basically, run the following command as root, oopsie!

`man shred`

> Overwrite the selected FILE(s) repeatedly, in order to make it harder to recover the data.
>
> -r  recursive
>
> -f  force change permissions to allow writing
>
> -z  add a final overwrite with zeros to hide shredding
>
> ~/* from the user's home directory root

Ouch, not a simple delete here, overwrite the files a default three times, follow the folder structure, change the permissions to allow this on read only files, add a zero overwrite.

Well, at least they weren't totally out to destroy you, you didn't do `rm -rf` from `/` (and no, don't ever do this unless you want to wipe a drive, you're facing a total system reinstall)

The only way to fix the damage done here is to restore from backups.

Comment: "Stuff happens... be prepared for stuff happening" you should replace that and use Murphy's law...